# Company does not do yearly review

Tags: performance-reviews

After working for almost three years, I am yet to have a "yearly" performance review - or a review of any kind. Is this a red flag? How common is it for companies to avoid or forget about reviews?

Comment: Are you getting any sort of periodic pay increase without the review?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I make enough and anecdotally I hear no companies are giving any raises due to the economic situation (US). Even so, I would like to have an idea of how I am doing and how much value I bring to the table.

Comment: The plural of anecdote is not "data". There are **lots** of companies still giving annual raises, bonuses, etc (my employer is doing it, my spouse's is not) in the US. The economic situation is not universally bad in the country right now and it's a weak excuse for many companies to just get out of giving raises & bonuses (keeping the spoils for executives, shareholders or the company coffers). Just remember that every year you *don't* increase your income, you are effectively making *less* money thanks to inflation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is this a red flag?

Some companies hold annual reviews, others do not.

If this is one of those companies who don't have annual reviews, then going three years without one isn't a red flag.

If this company used to hold annual reviews, then stopped for three years without telling employees why, then that is cause for concern.

> How common is for companies to avoid or forget about reviews?

It mostly depends on the industry and locale.

I work in software, and the only companies I have ever worked for who didn't have annual reviews were early-stage startups.

My wife works for dentists and has never worked for one who ever held annual reviews.

More important than formal annual reviews is

- getting the feedback you need about your work and performance
- getting raises and/or promotions that are warranted

None of these depend on a formal annual review process. If you aren't getting these, talk to your boss. Ask for feedback, and talk about a raise if you think one is due.

Don't wait for a formal process to be implemented.

Answer (score 6):

When I worked for others I never waited until an anniversary date to solicit feedback from my boss.  Usually about once every 3 months I'd be in their office asking how they thought things were going.

Also, I've never waited for a company to just give me a raise.  I ask when I think the times appropriate.  At one company, that was every 3 months because I was seriously under paid and my job kept changing.  At another I felt (and research showed) I was so over paid that I didn't bother bringing it up for 3 years.

Point is: if you want feedback, ask your boss in an informal setting.  If you think it's time for a raise, ask your boss with the door closed.